# Using processes to run commands with pipes

Tags: c, process, pipe, exec, dup2

I'm still new to processes,pipes and dup2, therefore I'd like someone to help me figure out what's wrong with a program I've created. This program is supposed to run `ls | wc`. So far the output I get is :

```
wc : standard input : Bad file descriptor
        0         0         0
ls : write error : Bad file descriptor
```

After I get this output, the terminal still accepts inputs. It's like wc is still running, although if I put commands like ls first(without any other input before) it runs them and shuts down. I tried running ps before/after and while the program was still running and it didn't show any process being open aside from bash and ps. (I'm running this program in Linux terminal)

Here's my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<errno.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
      pid_t pid;
      int fd[2];
      char com1[1024] = ("ls");
      char com2[1024] = ("wc");
      pipe(fd);
      pid = fork();
      if(pid == 0){
           open(fd[1]);
           dup2(fd[0],STDOUT_FILENO);
           close(fd[0]);
           execlp(com1, com1, NULL);
                  }
      else {
           pid = fork();
           if (pid == 0){
                   open(fd[0]);
                   dup2(fd[1],STDIN_FILENO);
                   close(fd[1]);
                   execlp(com2, com2, NULL);
                         }
           }
return 0;
}
```

Bear in mind that I know some if commands for checking are required(like `if(pid<0)exit(0);`) but I tried to simplify my code as much as possible in order to see if there's any mistake due to carelessness.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does that code even compile? It should at the very least cause the compiler to scream warnings at you. The call `open(fd[0])` (and of course `open(fd[1])`) is not valid and should be removed.

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you read [the `pipe` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html). Pay close attention to which of the descriptors are the read and the write end of the pipe.

Comment: This code compiles without any errors so far, I removed the open() commands and I get the same output

Comment: Did you fix the other issue too? With using the wrong end of the pipes?

Comment: I'm still in a dead end. Can't figure out how to use execlp correctly. I think I understand the theory behind pipes, still I can't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the `pipe` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html):

> `pipefd[0]` refers to the read end of the pipe.  `pipefd[1]` refers to the write end of the pipe.

Now take this line from the first child, the process that calls the `ls` command:

```
dup2(fd[0],STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Here you duplicate the *read* end of the pipe to `STDOUT_FILENO`, i.e. where output is written. If you stop and think a little about it, how would you write to a read-only file-descriptor like `fd[0]`?

Same with the other child process, where you make the *write* end of the pipe standard input.

The solution is simple: Swap places of the descriptors you duplicate. Use `fd[1]` for the first child process, and `fd[0]` for the second child process.

In the first process where you call the `ls` command:

```
dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
close(fd[1]);
execlp(com1, com1, NULL);
```

And in the second child process where you call the `wc` command:

```
dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
close(fd[0]);
execlp(com2, com2, NULL);
```